# rails trigger controller from hitting mailto button?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails, I want the user to hit the mailto button and then call the method 'mail' in controller 'home' , how you do that??

Here is my code, it seems doesnt work well...

```
= mail_to boss.email :subject=>boss.subj,    
:body=>"hi boss", :action=>'home#mail'
```

And is there anyway can make mail_to open a new windows to my mail box?
now when I hit mail_to and then select gmail (firefox ubuntu), then I go straight to gmail...
I want it open in new windows... anyway to do it in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to exactly. It does not make sens to provide

```
:action => 'home#mail'
```

to the mail_to method. This will simply open your default email client and fill in the values for subject, email address and body. If you want to call a action in a controller, you have to do it with link_to. And think about using [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for this task ...