# Connecting SendGrid with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sendgrid

I have created a new Action Mailer that will allow me to be notified by email when someone clicks on the "Click to Connect" button. I'm following a tutorial and was able to successfully set up the connection with SendGrid on Heroku from my "contact us" button. Currently when I click the button it opens my computer's email app instead of triggering the SendGrip app.

users/show.html.erb

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3 text-center'>
        <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'user-show-avatar' %>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <h1><%= @user.profile.first_name %></h1>
        <h3><%= @user.profile.city %>, <%= @user.profile.state %>, <%= @user.profile.country %></h3>
        <div class='well profile-block profile-description'>
            <h4>Bio</h4>
            <p><%= @user.profile.bio %></p>
            <h4>Coding Languages</h4>
            <p><%= @user.profile.coding_languages %></p>
            <h4>Mentoring Needs</h4>
            <p><%= @user.profile.mentoring_needs %></p>
        </div class='connect_button'>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block active" href="mailto:connections@jrdevmentoring.com" role="button">Click to Connect</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

mailers/connection_mailer.rb

```
class ConnectionsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default to: 'connections@jrdevmentoring.com'

    def connection_email(name, email, body)
        @name = name
        @email = email
        @body = body
        mail(from: email, subject: 'Jr. Dev Mentoring Connect Form Message')
    end
end
```

config/environment.rb

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_startstls_auto => true
}
```

**Update**: I need the button at the bottom on the users/show.html.erb to send the user to this form, instead of opening my email app. And then the button on this page needs to connect to SendGrid.

views/connections/new.html.erb

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <h1 class="text-center">Let's Connect</h1>
      <h5 class="text-center">I'd like to connect with...</h5> 
      <div class="well">
        <%= form_for @connection do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :your_name, "Your Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :your_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email, "Your Email" %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :comments, "Connection's Name" %>
            <%= f.text_area :connections_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>

          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails trigger controller from hitting mailto button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407672/rails-trigger-controller-from-hitting-mailto-button)

Comment: Which tutorial are you following ?

Comment: @Laurens Coder Manual...I'm using the tutorial as a starting point for the app I'm building so this feature is a deviation from the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a form and post the form parameters to an action in a controller, the following post has everything you need: [Contact Form Mailer in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769772/contact-form-mailer-in-rails-4)

Comment: I followed the link you provided and others with no success

Answer (score 0):

you should remove mailto from href

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block active" 
href="mailto:connections@jrdevmentoring.com" role="button">Click to Connect</a>
```

that's why is opening the email app